# Javascript's Object has different data at a time

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

```
for(var i=0; i<Elements.length; i++)
{   if( Elements[i].y < 0 )
    {
       console.log({y:Elements[i].y, E:Elements[i]});
    }
}
```

==========================================================
and the console shows to me next result:

```
Object {y: -100, E: Element}
    E: Element
      x: 200
      y: 200
    __proto__: Element

   y: -100
   __proto__: Object
```

==============================

It is pretty strange. The *Elements[i].y* has **-100**, whereas within itself *Elements[i]* the *"y"* has **200**
One object has different data at a time.
Example of the console is for illustrative purposes.
The expected value is 200 instead of -100.
What's wrong? Please help.

Comment: Consoles are funny creatures. When you do `y:Elements[i].y`, you're copying the value of `.y` to the new object's property. But when you do `E:Elements[i]`, you're making a reference to the object. So when you finally view the data in the console, you're seeing a snapshot of `.y` via the `y` property, but a current picture of the entire object via the `E` property. In other words, the copy of `.y` is the value when the loop is running, but the `E:` reference shows the value when the console is displayed.

Comment: ...try this: `console.log({y:Elements[i].y, E:JSON.stringify(Elements[i])});`. Now assuming the properties are enumerable, you'll get a serialized snapshot of the object (at least it's non-inherited properties), as it looked during the loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Comment: @Crazy Train: thanks for your reply. I have tried JSON.stringify, it shows -100, but it does not solve the problem because the program produces different results. The expected value is 200 instead of -100.

Comment: You have some code somewhere that is changing it to `-100`. Must be happening sometime after the loop. Can't tell from the code in your question.

Comment: @Crazy Train: What could happen while command "console.log()" is running?

Comment: @ILMIR: Nothing. But something is happening after it's running. In other words, the loop runs and invokes `console.log()`, and you see the correct values when you use `JSON.stringify()`. But then sometime after the loop, but before you need to use the data, the values are being changed. So you need to track down where that's happening.

Comment: @Crazy Train: My fault. As you said my object data were changed after the loop. Thanks for help! :)